# Is my decision diagram for the root test in the most general form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I created a decision diagram for the root test:

[image]

*File [Decision diagram for the root test.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Decision_diagram_for_the_root_test.svg) of [Stephan Kulla](http://kulla.me) licensed under [CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en)*

Is there any case missing or is it possible to formulate one of the cases in a more general form? I want to make sure that after three "No's" there is really no way to apply the root test...

Comment: This seems to cover even more than what is written in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can probably almost arbitrarly refine that diagram further at the expense of complexity. For example: if $(a_n)$ does not alternate and

$$\text{if } \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} \geq \sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k}} \text{ for almost all } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{, then } \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \text{ diverges.}$$

In my opinion your diagram is sufficient since the target group seems to be students new to the subject. I think most books do not even cover the bottom case.

Comment: you mean "if $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} \ge \frac 1{k^k}$ for almost all ..."?!

Comment: added "$k \in \mathbb{N}$" and "$(a_n)$ does not alternate". If $(a_n)$ alternated the series could indeed converge by the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: I meant that in the inequality $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \ge \frac 1{k^k}$ you have mixed the variables $k$ and $n$... In the current form I doubt that your statement is right: Take $(a_n)$ any positive sequence such that $\sum a_n$ converges. Because $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac 1{k^k} = 0$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we find for almost all $k$ the inequality $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \ge \frac 1{k^k}$...

Comment: Do you mean "if $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} \ge \sqrt[k]{\frac 1k}$ for almost all $k\in\mathbb N$ then $\sum a_k$ diverges"?!

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! Fingers faster than the brain! Sorry for the confusion.